# how do I quote an HTML snippet without rendering the HTML itself?

Tags: html, vue.js

I've run into some odd behavior. I have a VueJS app in which I am trying to quote some HTML that's in use on the site. I'd like to render it like so:

```
<h2>
  {{ pomodoro.longBreak }}
</h2>
```

I've wrapped it in `<code>` tags, those in `<pre>` tags, and replaced the angle and curly braces with HTML entities, as in the following:

```
<pre>
  <code>
&lt;h1&gt;
  &lbrace;&lbrace; pomodoro.longBreak &rbrace;&rbrace;
&lt;/h1&gt;
  </code>
</pre>
```

which results in:

```
<h2>
  15
</h2>
```

where '15' is the value of `pomodoro.longBreak`.
I don't want the value to be rendered, just the raw HTML. If I put a space in between the pairs of `&lbrace` and `&rbrace`, I get this:

```
<h2>
  { { pomodoro.longBreak } }
</h2>
```

which is pretty close to what I want, but I'd like to be able to display it as it's actually typed.

Is there an HTML only solution to this?

Comment: ^^^^ Yeah, the answer in that dupe will solve this, you're looking for [the `v-pre` directive](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-pre).

Comment: You'll add the directive to your code tag: `<code v-pre>`, [here's an example with that in action](https://jsbin.com/xasemahifi/2/edit?html,js,output). Also worth noting that escaping the curly braces becomes optional with `v-pre`, but you'll still need to escape the angled brackets `<>` like you're already doing.